# Разбивка текста на предложения и слова

Tags: c#, linq

Задача с юлёрна 
https://ulearn.me/course/basicprogramming/Praktika_Parser_predlozheniy__d41a27ad-a377-4fbd-ba1c-1bd761c69dd1

Поступающую строку нужно разделить сначала на "предложения", потом эти "предложения" разделить на "слова".

"предложения" отделены друг от друга одним из следующих символов `.!?;:()`

а "слова" могут состоять только из букв и символа апострофа ', отделены друг от друга любыми другими символами.

Метод должен возвращать список предложений, где каждое предложение — это список из одного или более слов в нижнем регистре `List<List<string>>`. 
вот мое решение:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace TextAnalysis
{
    static class SentencesParserTask
    {
        
        public static List<List<string>> ParseSentences(string text)
        {
            return SplitSentencesIntoWords(SplitIntoSentences(text));
        }
        
        public static string[] SplitIntoSentences(string text)
        {
            text = text.ToLower();
            char[] separators = {';','!','?','.',':','(',')'};
            string[] sentences = text.Split(separators).Where(x => x != string.Empty && x != null).ToArray();
        
            return sentences;    
        }

        public static List<List<string>> SplitSentencesIntoWords(string[] sentences)
        {
            var sentencesList = new List<List<string>>();
            
            foreach (string sentence in sentences)
            {
                var wordStartIndex = -1;
                List<string> words = new List<string>();
            
                for (int i = 0; i < sentence.Length;  i++)
                {
                    if (char.IsLetter(sentence[i]) || sentence[i].Equals('\'') )
                    {
                        if (wordStartIndex == -1)
                        {
                            wordStartIndex = i;
                            words.Add(sentence.Substring(wordStartIndex, 1));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            words.Add(sentence.Substring(wordStartIndex+1, i - wordStartIndex));
                            wordStartIndex = -1;
                        }
                        
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        wordStartIndex = -1;
                    }
                }   

                if (words.Count > 0)
                {
                        var wordsArray = words.ToArray();
                        string result = string.Join("", wordsArray);
                        List<string> list = new List<string> {result};
                        sentencesList.Add(list);
                }
            }
            return sentencesList;        
        }       
    }
}
```

**при входной строке "abc" метод ParseSentences() должен возвращать {{"abc"}} (что он и делает в моем варианте)** 
**при входной строке "b, c"  метод ParseSentences() должен возвращать {{"b","c"}} (в моем варианте {{"bc"}})**

как мне words добавлять нужно к sentencesList, чтобы метод для любого ввода работал верно? 
помогите пожалуйста(

Comment: .NET Framework?

Comment: ...или .NET Core?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ кстати, да. вопрос к спрашивающему: вы примеры брали из задания или из головы?

Comment: примеры из задания

Comment: @Karlusha если все остальные тесты у вас работают (с пробелами в начале и в конце, м-ду, 1-м или несколькими и т.д.), то вопрос не имеет смысла: невнимательные составители задач не проверили самого простого — тесты!

Comment: @return Я вроде как погорячился, ибо запятая тут идет как разделитель слов, а не предложений и в том списке ее быть не должно. То есть `b, c` - это одно предложение и `b` с `c` - это слова, которые у автора сливаются в одно целое на выходе.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ тогда запятую можно просто считать пробелом (если нет условия на проверку "больше 1-й запятой подряд быть не может"). всё же, это вопрос не ко мне, а к Karlusha.

Comment: `.Where(x => x != string.Empty && x != null)` - `x` после сплита не может быть `null`, а чтобы убрать пустые строки проще добавить параметр `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` в вызов `Split`, тогда надобность в `Where` вообще отпадает, и так как Split возвращает массив - вызов `ToArray` тоже не нужен

Answer (score 0, accepted):

нужно было просто рассмотреть ВСЕ возможные варианты событий 
менять нужно было вот этот метод:

```
 public static List<List<string>> SplitSentencesIntoWords(string[] sentences)
        {
            var sentencesList = new List<List<string>>();
            
            foreach (string sentence in sentences)
            {
                var wordStartIndex = -1; var wordEndIndex = -1;
                List<string> words = new List<string>();
            
                for (int i = 0; i < sentence.Length;  i++)
                {
                    if (char.IsLetter(sentence[i]) || sentence[i].Equals('\'') )
                    {
                        if (wordStartIndex == -1)
                        {
                            wordStartIndex = i;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            wordEndIndex = i;
                        }
                        if(i == sentence.Length - 1)
                        {
                           if(wordStartIndex != -1)
                           {
                               if(wordEndIndex != -1)
                               {
                                  words.Add(sentence.Substring(wordStartIndex, wordEndIndex-wordStartIndex+1));
                               }
                               else
                               {
                                  words.Add(sentence.Substring(wordStartIndex, 1));
                               }
                           }                    
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(wordStartIndex != -1)
                        {
                            if(wordEndIndex != -1)
                            {
                                words.Add(sentence.Substring(wordStartIndex, wordEndIndex-wordStartIndex+1));
                                wordEndIndex = -1;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                words.Add(sentence.Substring(wordStartIndex, 1));
                            }
                            wordStartIndex = -1;
                        }               
                    }
                }   

                if (words.Count > 0)
                {
                        sentencesList.Add(words);  
                }
            }
            return sentencesList;        
        }       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```cs
static readonly char[] seps = { ... }; // либо `HashSet<char>`
```

```cs
bool TrySeparateToSentences(string? input, out string[]?[]? sentences)
{
    sentences = null;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input)) return true;

    var sents = new List<List<string>>();

    for (var i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        if (char.IsWhiteSpace(input[i]))
            continue;
        else if (char.IsLetterOrDigit(input[i])) // использовать ваш метод определения символа слова
                                                 // (например, учитывать контрольные символы; тогда
                                                 // определяем категорию и по ней с помощью локальной
                                                 // функции, возвращающей `bool`, выполняем нижеуказанные
                                                 // инструкции)
        {
           if (sents.Count == 0) sents.Add(new List<string>());

            var start = i;

            while (i < input.Length && char.IsLetterOrDigit(input[i])) i++;

            var word = input.Substring(start, i - start);

            sents[^1].Add(word);
        }
        else if (seps.Contains(input[i]))
            sents.Add(new List<string>());
        else
            return false;

     if (sents.Count == 0) return true;

     sentences = new string[sents.Count][];

     for (var i = 0; i < sentences.Length; i++)
         sentences[i] = sents[i].Count == 0 ? null : sents[i].ToArray();

     return true;
}
```

<sup>**Примечание**. Реализация сделана без использования `Span`/`ReadOnlySpan` и `Range` для совместимости с .NET Framework.</sup>